# Check for Active WordPress Plugins from the Block Editor

Tags: plugins, block-editor

StackExchange Community,

I am working on some Block Editor formats and blocks and would like to add a check to see if a certain plugin is installed. This would be specific to the back-end admin area of WordPress. For example something along the lines of:

```
if ( isPluginActive('plugin-name') ) {
 console.log('Plugin is active.')
}
```

I am aware that I could localize the data from PHP to my script but it would be much better to use any built in functions or packages if it is available. I did come across the `getPlugins()` method from the plugins package but this seems to refer to gutenberg plugins rather than WordPress plugins.

Update:
I attempted to use apiFetch and was able to retrieve a list of installed plugins along with the status of each.

```
const isPluginActive = () => {
    apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/plugins' } ).then( ( plugins ) => {
        plugins.forEach( ( plugin ) => {
            const name = plugin.plugin
            const status = plugin.status
            
            if ( name === 'plugin-name/plugin-name' && status === 'active') {
                return true
            }
        })
    })
}
```

However, I am unsure how to use this to return a boolean response as a variable or function which I can use on my conditionals. It currently returns undefined.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that requires this check? Any context you add will help inform an appropriate answer, and could even reveal approaches you weren't aware of

Comment: Basically I have a cpt with it's own <PluginDocumentSettingPanel> adding fields specific to the cpt itself. I have some specific fields and conditionals that have been added to make provision for another plugin that has been added. I want those provisions to be removed if the plugin is inactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of Gutenberg's data stores expose selectors for this purpose yet, to the best of my knowledge. If any did, I would have expected to find it on [`core`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core/). If and when the Gutenberg experience expands to the plugin management screen I reckon we'll see such a thing implemented.

For the time being, if the relevant users have the `activate_plugins` capability, you could acquire this data from the Plugins REST API endpoint using the `@wordpress/api-fetch` package:

```
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';

// ...
const plugins = await apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/plugins' } );
```

The objects produced by the request will have [the fields described by the endpoint's schema](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/plugins/#schema), including the relative path to the main file, the name, version number, and active/inactive status.

It is possible to modify the permissions check callback for a core REST endpoint in order to expose this functionality to more users - but it's not very direct, and generally inadvisable. Creating a new endpoint or controller would probably be a better solution if you need to customize it's behavior.